# How is it possible for the mean of a log-normal distribution to have units?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, means, moment-generating-functions

I have a set of measurements $a$ (units m) which are log-normally distributed (with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$). The expected value (or mean) of $a$ is just the first arithmetic moment, i.e.

$$
E(a)=\int_0^\infty a f_A(a)\ da,
$$

where $f_A(a)$ is the probability density function with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. For the log-normal distribution, the solution to this integral is [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments)

$$
E(a) = \exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma\right).
$$

This implies that $E(a)$ (or the mean of $a$) has no units, since the argument of an exponential cannot have units. However, $E(a)$ obviously has units (m), which we can also clearly see from the integral. This seems like a contradiction, so I'm clearly missing something. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: There is a hidden constant $1\,\text{m}$ multiplied to the exponential that makes $E(a)$ have unit $[\text{m}]$.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this actually the answer? Would this constant appear from a full derivation of the solution to that integral?

Comment: Indeed, yes. If $A$ is a sample from the measurement, then $A$ is of the form
$$ A = k\exp(Z) $$
where $k$ is a conversion factor that carries all the units $A$, and $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is a (unitless) normal random variable. Then you can check that $$\mathbf{E}[A]=k\exp\left(\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right).$$

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: Another point of view is that you can turn any measurement into a unitless quantity by choosing an appropriate reference quantity. But that's really just the conversion-factor-with-units $k$ again, only you're (in effect) writing $A/k = \exp(Z)$ in order to have unitless quantities on both sides of the equation rather than writing $A=k\exp(Z)$.